# Set angular material drop down default value from the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to set the default value on angular material drop down from the controller.So far I got this:

```
<md-select ng-model="$ctrl.selected.displayType" ng-change="$ctrl.getDisplayType($ctrl.selected.displayType)">
    <md-option ng-repeat="display in $ctrl.displayTypes" ng-value="display">{{display.Name }}</md-option>
</md-select>


var self = this;
self.displayTypes = [{ "Name": 'All' }, { "Name": 'Active' }, { "Name": 'Non Active' }];

self.display = { "Name": 'All' };
```

Comment: You should use `ng-model-options` and `trackBy` to specify the default value. see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42832848/3543808)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `selected.displayType` variable as reference form the array like this

```
var self = this;
self.displayTypes = [{ "Name": 'All' }, { "Name": 'Active' }, { "Name": 'Non Active' }];

self.selected.displayType= self.displayTypes[0]
```

Edited

i made some changes in order to make this work. check whether it's compatible with your requirement

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("appctrl",function($scope){

var self = this;
self.displayTypes = [{ "Name": 'All' }, { "Name": 'Active' }, { "Name": 'Non Active' }];

self.selected = self.displayTypes[0].Name;

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appctrl as ctrl">
 <select ng-model="ctrl.selected" ng-change="ctrl.getDisplayType(ctrl.selected)" >
    <option ng-repeat="display in ctrl.displayTypes" value="{{display.Name}}">{{display.Name }}</option>
</select>

{{ctrl.selected }}
</div>
```

Comment: @sachilaranawaka Your answer looks great and will work in pure angular, however things get little complicated when we use angular material. see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42832848/3543808)

Answer (score 0):

Go through [md-select object equality](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect#selects-and-object-equality).

So according to the angular material docs we should specify an unique key for track by in ng-model-options to work around the issue.
`ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.Name'}`

```js
angular.module('BlankApp', ['ngMaterial']);

angular
  .module('BlankApp')
  .controller('AppCtrl', function() {
    var self = this;
    self.displayTypes = [{
      "Name": 'All'
    }, {
      "Name": 'Active'
    }, {
      "Name": 'Non Active'
    }];

    //setting the default value
    self.$onInit = function() {
      self.selected = {};
      self.selected.displayType = self.displayTypes[0];
    };

  });
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Angular Material style sheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="BlankApp" ng-cloak>
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl as $ctrl" class="md-padding selectdemoBasicUsage" ng-cloak="" layout="column" ng-app="MyApp">
    <div layout="row">
      <md-input-container>
        <label>State</label>
        <md-select ng-model="$ctrl.selected.displayType" ng-change="$ctrl.getDisplayType($ctrl.selected.displayType)" ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.Name'}">
          <md-option ng-repeat="display in $ctrl.displayTypes" ng-value="display">{{display.Name }}</md-option>
        </md-select>
      </md-input-container>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Angular Material Library -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```